# one of my if statement do not work in python

Tags: python, list, if-statement, printing

this is a simple code for telegram bot.
I have a list, When the user types "m", its name is added to the list and the robot publishes the list,
When the user types "n", the name is deleted from the list and publishes the list,
When the number of the list is equal to 2, the bot should say "Done: and not receive another amount When the number of the list is equal to 0 The robot should say "No one" and publishes the list.

but when I run this code,when list equals to 0 nothing happens!

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
#coding=UTF-8

from telegram.ext import Updater , CommandHandler , Filters , 
CommandHandler , MessageHandler
from telegram import MessageEntity
from telegram import ParseMode , InputTextMessageContent

updater = Updater("BOT TOKEN")

listt = []


def msg_filter(bot , update):
    wordsp = ['m']
    wordsn = ['n']



    if any (i in update.message.text for i in wordsp) and " 
    {}".format(update.message.from_user.first_name) not in listt:

    listt.append("{}".format(update.message.from_user.first_name))
    bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = 
    "\n".join(listt))
    bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = len(listt))

       if len(listt)==2:
           bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = 
           "Done")

    if any (i in update.message.text for i in wordsn) and " 
    {}".format(update.message.from_user.first_name)  in listt:


    listt.remove("{}".format(update.message.from_user.first_name))
    bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = 
    "\n".join(listt))

    bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = len(listt))

       if len(listt)==0:
       bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = 
       "nobody")



print(listt)
print(len(listt))

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text , msg_filter ))
updater.start_polling()
```

Comment: Your formatting and indentation is incorrect in the code bit of the question. Please fix it.

Comment: sorry I don't know how to fix it, that's why I asked here, can you help me about correct indentation?

Comment: If you can run your code, and it doesn't throw an error, then your indentation is different in your code than here in SO. If you can't run it and get an error, you should post that error as well. From your question's "but when I run this code,when list equals to 0 nothing happens!" it seems to me that your original indentation is correct.

Comment: Btw; Downvotes don't mean you did anything bad. You just didn't ask the question like it should be asked. Please tell us exactly what you want to know, where your problem is, what you've tried, what your expected output is and what your current output is. If you have any errors please post them alongside. Again, nothing bad, keep asking questions but put effort in it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this will solve your indentation issues:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
#coding=UTF-8

from telegram.ext import Updater , CommandHandler , Filters , CommandHandler , MessageHandler
from telegram import MessageEntity
from telegram import ParseMode , InputTextMessageContent

updater = Updater("BOT TOKEN")

listt = []


def msg_filter(bot , update):
    wordsp = ['m']
    wordsn = ['n']



    if any (i in update.message.text for i in wordsp) and "{}".format(update.message.from_user.first_name) not in listt:
        listt.append("{}".format(update.message.from_user.first_name))
        bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = "\n".join(listt))
        bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = len(listt))

        if len(listt)==2:
            bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = "Done")

    if any (i in update.message.text for i in wordsn) and " {}".format(update.message.from_user.first_name)  in listt:
        listt.remove("{}".format(update.message.from_user.first_name))
        bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = "\n".join(listt))
        bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = len(listt))

        if len(listt)==0:
            bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = "nobody")



print(listt)
print(len(listt))

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text , msg_filter ))
updater.start_polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about the order of execution.

- You define the list to be empty.
- You *define* the handler function (but not call it) that changes the list.
- You print the information about the list (which is still empty).
- You register your handler function.
- You start polling.

I.e. you have not changed the list before you print it.

You need to move the print statements inside the function. I also cleaned up your code as it appears broken in your question.

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
# coding=UTF-8

from telegram.ext import Updater, Filters, MessageHandler

updater = Updater("BOT TOKEN")

listt = []


def msg_filter(bot, update):
    wordsp = ["m"]
    wordsn = ["n"]

    if any(i in update.message.text for i in wordsp) and "{}".format(update.message.from_user.first_name) not in listt:

        listt.append("{}".format(update.message.from_user.first_name))
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="\n".join(listt))
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=len(listt))

        if len(listt) == 2:
            bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Done")

    if any(i in update.message.text for i in wordsn) and "{}".format(update.message.from_user.first_name) in listt:
        listt.remove("{}".format(update.message.from_user.first_name))
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="\n".join(listt))

        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=len(listt))

    if len(listt) == 0:
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="nobody")

    print(listt)
    print(len(listt))


updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, msg_filter))
updater.start_polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function takes 2 arguments but never called ? or am I missing something here. You can declare the list as global like this so it wont end up empty, after the function is called.

```
def msg_filter(bot, update):
    global listt
```